# Probability: A Jar holds 25 crayons

Tags: probability

A jar holds 25 crayons: 8 red, 6 blue, 5 green and 2 each of yellow, purple and pink. If Sydney takes one crayon, and Farrah takes another, what is the probability that NEITHER one takes a green crayon?

I know that the probability of NOT choosing a green on the first draw is 20/25. The second draw would be 19/24. What do I do now?

Comment: Multiply, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Looks good, now you multiply the probabilities to get your final answer!

Comment: That's it. Thanks! I was thinking 19x20 would be a weird numerator, but it all divides by 20 to get 19/30 and that is one of the answer choices!